# Работа с временем в PHP

Tags: php

Все еще борюсь с временем (.

У меня есть форма с селектами, где нужно выбирать:

- 1-й селект - Цикл День недели (Дата),
- 2-й селект Часы,
- 3-й селект - Минуты

Атрибут value первого селекта - d.m. Атрибуты value 2 и 3-го селектов - числа 00 до 23 и 00 до 59.

Мне нужно, чтобы 3 селекта соеденить: типа `date("11.12 19:40")` и перевести это в UNIX time();

P.S strtotime() не помогает, просто не работает(;

Если что-то не понятно, напишите мне на e-mail (в профиле) свои icq или скайп, очень надо, помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"))
```

Comment: Оно вернет UNIX формат ? спасибо )

Comment: да, вернет.